# Print a taxonomy term and url D8 views template

Tags: views, theming

I am totally new to drupal 8. I have used d7 and i am migrating now.

I have setup a view with 4 articles.

I have managed to print out in a custom views theme

1. my title
2. image url

```
 {% for row in content['#view'].result %}


   {% set image_uri = row._entity.field_image.entity.uri.value %}


   {{ image_uri|image_style('blog_298x200') }}

   {{ content['#view'].field['title'].value(row) }} 



 {% endfor %}
```

My template file is called : **block--views-block--main-article-block-miniatures-slider.html.twig**

I would be very greateful for any tip for getting what i need :

1. The node url
2. The taxonomy (field_categorie) and its url
3. Created date

I have installed the tweak twig module to make things easier for me

Comment: IMO drop the complexity and use a view mode output for the view. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/display-modes-view-modes-and-form-modes

Comment: Well i want  to use the view block to show up news as slider. Also i do not want to install any module for that

Comment: View modes don't require a module and the block can still be used.